# CakePhp3 select() in query more than one tier

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

Is it possible to get columns of tables which are two or more tables remote by using **select()**?

```
$rooms = TableRegistry::get('Rooms')
    ->find()
    ->contain(['Levels.Buildings'])
    ->toArray();
```

... this works, but returns ervery column of the three tables

```
$rooms = TableRegistry::get('Rooms')
    ->find()
    ->select(['Buildings.name'])
    ->contain(['Levels.Buildings'])
    ->toArray();
```

... this returns nothing, althought the generated select statement seems to be correct

Comment: What are the relationships between the tables?

Comment: i think you leed me to the problem.... it seems that the select works only at **N:1** ... in my example ... if **Rooms** belongsTo **Levels** and **Levels** belongsTo **Buildings**, it would work.
In case of **N:M** or **1:N** i can't use **select()** isn'it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only select fields in the primary query if you are handling a one-to-one relationship (*i.e.* `hasOne` or `belongsTo`). This is presumably your issue. In which case you need to specify the fields to include from your has-many relationship in the `contain` itself:-

```
$rooms = TableRegistry::get('Rooms')
    ->find()
    ->contain([
        'Levels' => [
            'Buildings' => [
                'fields' => 'name'
            ]
        ]
    ])
    ->toArray();
```

This is because CakePHP will perform a second separate query to retrieve the has-many associated model data for which you need to specify the query conditions within the `contain`.